# Best books/courses to learn Computer Networks from a backend web developer's perspective?

Tags: self-learning

Please recommend some books/courses.
My problem is this:

- This is not the first time I am studying computer networks. I studied in CS degree.
- I bought Kurose Ross, Fourouzan books on networking and feel like did a big mistake as they contain information which I already know of.
- I also bought Douglas Comer Internetworking With TCP/IP and it seems good. Recommend me something more like this.
- CCNA is too cisco centric and I looked at net+ and it looks so basic.
- I know at this level I should be reading books specialized on DNS, SSL, SSH...etc to learn advanced concepts, but I want a refresher which is a bit challenging.
- Books like unix network programming aren't necessary for me as I am not a systems programmer. I want helicopter view of how networking concepts will be useful for me to design a system. For example: Leaky bucket is used in api rate limiting. Like that. Something that makes things fun for me.
- I've bought books/courses on wireshark, web security etc and I think that's helping me. So recommend something like that.
- As  a system administrator, I need to understand how networking commands work under the hood so that I can troubleshoot them. Not how they're programmed, but how they work from the view of computer networking.

https://www.cbtnuggets.com/blog/technology/programming/20-essential-linux-network-monitoring-and-configuration-commands

These are the commands I need to know of how they work. I've already read the man pages of most of these commands. They tell stuffs from unix pov, but I want to learn the networking pov of these commands.